# Importing Source code in FTP folder to VSTS

Tags: import, ftp, azure-devops, ipa, source-code-protection

A third party is building a mobile application for my company and they developing using XCode. They have given their source code to us using SFTP server so the code now resides in an FTP folder that has restricted access. How can I import this source code into VSTS? The folder containing source code has zip files and a .ipa file.

Comment: What type of repository? TFVC or Git? Have you tried anything?

Comment: Is it ok for you to copy the source code (in zip file) in your local machine, then unzip and manage in VSTS VCS (version control system)? And what's the VCS do you want to use, Git or TFVC?

Comment: @DanielMann I'm supposed to be using Git repo but I don't know where to start.

Comment: @MarinaLiu-MSFT we already have a Git repo in place within VSTS.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The are [a few things you need to do](https://ilclubdellesei.wordpress.com/2017/10/29/how-to-get-started-with-visual-studio-team-services/):

1. Create a new Project in VSTS (skip this step if you already have a project).
2. Init a repository
3. Upload the repository

Comment: I just have zip files and .ipa file in the folder they are checking into. Can I just go ahead and upload all the files? how do make sure the later code check-ins are being updated to VSTS?